# Journey Builder Custom Activity Id on Running Hover

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Im developing a custom activity for Journey Builder that requires a hover over state showing stats that will come from my server. Because the hover over url needs to be defined in the `config.json` on initialization, I have no idea *which* custom activity the hover over request is coming from.

For example, if I have two custom activities in my activated Journey, the requests that I get from each hover over event look exactly the same. I need to display different data on hover for each custom activity, but the requests to the server are identical.

I understand that I can use Postmonger to get *some* data, but for example if I inspect the payload from the `initActivityRunningHover` the data is still in the templating language format:

`{
  "name": "",
  "arguments": {
    "executionMode": "{{Context.ExecutionMode}}",
    "definitionId": "{{Context.DefinitionId}}",
    "activityId": "{{Activity.Id}}",
    "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
    "execute":
...`

If there is any way at the point of hover over state I could know the "activityId" I can use it to send back the correct data to display on hover over.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

probably you have found it yourself, but I've founded that value of **id** attribute is the same as {{Activity.Id}} which will be send later from MC during execute request ...

```
{
"name":"***",
"id":"245a57af-8394-431a-9f60-62c457e8d50e",
"key":"REST-1","type":"REST",
"arguments":{
"executionMode":"{{Context.ExecutionMode}}",
"definitionId":"{{Context.DefinitionId}}",
"activityId":"{{Activity.Id}}",
"contactKey":"{{Context.ContactKey}}"...
```

Hope this can help ...